# How can I loop over a dictionary and write the name of the key as the name of the output file?

Tags: python

I want to loop over a dictionary and make an output file for each key in the dictionary and use the key as the name of the output file. This is what I tried:

```
for id, pos in PNposD.iteritems():
  print id, 'id'
  print pos, 'pos'
  ofh = open("/home/",id,"_candMuts.txt")
  ofh.write("%d\n" % (pos))
```

and this is the error message i got for the line where i try to open the input file (in line 4):

```
TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format). You should open the file with write mode (`w`) to write something to the file.

```
for id, pos in PNposD.iteritems():
    print id, 'id'
    print pos, 'pos'
    with open("/home/{}_candMuts.txt".format(id), 'w') as ofh:
        ofh.write("%d\n" % (pos))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ofh = open("/home/%d_candMuts.txt"%id, "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving the three parts of the file name as separate arguments to `open`, join them together by any of the usual methods:

```
import os.path
open(os.path.join("/home", "%s_candMuts.txt" % id)
```

And it's better not to use `id` as a name, because it's also a built-in function.